# What is added to Tikkun Hatsot during the daytime of Ben Ha'metzarim?

Tags: three-weeks, tikkun-chatzot

I cannot seem to find the text online anywhere. I know it is in some Sepharadi siddurim.

Answer (score 1):

[image: first of three]

[image: second of three]

[image: third of three]

These photos are from the Ish Matzliach siddur. Added towards the end of the tikkun, usually noted in the regular Tikkun Hasot text. May we merit a geula shelema be'karov.